# Determine if a form element has any validators attached

Tags: validation, angularjs

Is it possible to determine if a form element has a validator attached? For example...

`<input type='text' required />` <--- has validator

`<input type='text'/>` <--- has none

I have a directive that assigns an image depending on whether something is valid or not but at the moment its showing its valid even when there are no validator rules assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You're in a directive:

```
var link = function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {}
```

Couldn't you check for `iAttrs.required`?

Alternatively, I'd implement Angular's `ng-required` directive on my inputs, then check the $dirty and $invalid flags on the form. Check this fiddle for more info: http://jsfiddle.net/EUQtN/

Comment: There might be other types of validator apart from required.

Answer (score 0):

The property NgModelController.$errors contains a list of the validators and their current value.